# Only overriding values with src/test/resources/application.properties for Integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an integration test that spins up a running copy of my Spring Boot rest api and performs tests with rest template. Currently I can use `src/test/resources/application.properties` to specify/override any properties I want to set for testing. The problem is that this doesn't only act as overriding, I have to duplicate all of the properties in `src/main/resources/application.properties` as well. Ideally I would like it to read both files and use the test properties to override any properties found in both files. This works for profile specific properties such as when using both `src/main/resources/application.properties` and `src/main/resources/application-dev.properties`, but doesn't seem to be the case for running tests. I know I can use a custom named properties file and pull that in with an annotation but I'd like to avoid that route to keep things clean.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Adding an `application-test.properties` to your `src/test/resources/` and enabling a `test` profile (or whatever you decide to use) should make it load both the `application.properties` from `src/main/resources` as well as the profile specific one from `src/test/resources`. Both should be on the class path with the `src/test/resources` one taking precedence over the main one (when running tests).

Comment: @M.Deinum Seems so obvious now, thank you this is what I was looking for. Didn't realize the profile specific property loading worked when running tests